# Manually creating a Dart http.Response<T> instance

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, dart-http

Im mocking a method that returns a `Future<Response<MyModel>>` . How do I create a `Response<MyModel>`? If I do `var response = Response<MyModel>(json.encode(data), 200);` I get an error: "The type 'Response' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given."

I'm using mockito for my mock, and I would prefer manually creating the mock instead of using `MockClient` from https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/http.testing-library.html

Comment: As far as I see, `Response` is not a generic class, meaning that we don't have such thing as `Response<MyModel>`, instead Response gets a string and a status code. That's why you get the error.

Comment: Ahh you are right, sorry, I am stupid. It was not a http.Response - it was a Dio Response class. Thank you